# Request MFA or OTP after logged in user

Tags: oauth-2.0, multi-factor-authentication

I have an application that use OAuth2 authentication provide by Active Directory Federation Services,MFA is requested upon login.

What I would like is that after a certain action on a webpage, MFA or an OTP code is requested also in this case. Without user logout.

The application is written in Javascript + Vue for frontend and C# for Backend.

What can be a solution?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

An OAuth / OpenID Connect authorization redirect can be triggered for reasons other than initial user login. One option is for the initial sign-in to use limited scopes, eg:

```
openid profile orders
```

Then, when you want to perform a higher privilege operation, make a new authorization redirect with higher privilege scopes:

```
openid profile orders payments
```

After login the new access token can be used by your APIs to allow the action. Some identity systems may also allow you to configure a scope time to live, so that the high privilege token only lives for the lifetime of the next access token.

Also take a look at the [acr_values and prompt](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthRequest) parameters, which allow you to control the authentication method used, and when it is required. The `acr_values` parameter can force use of a one time password, and the `prompt` parameter can avoid the use of the existing SSO session.

Note that I have not used ADFS for a few versions, and you will have to see if it supports these standards based behaviours.